# Removing the first items from a dynamic array when it gets to a certain size

Tags: arrays, vb.net, graphics, dynamic-arrays

I am making a gravity simulation which shows the trajectory of planets. Each planet leaves behind a trail of dots when it moves, which is stored in a dynamic array. However, when the trail becomes longer the paint event has to draw more every time so the frame rate decreases. I want to delete the first dots when the array gets larger than say 1000 dots.

This is in the code for the paint event:

```
For drawTrail As Integer = 0 To planet.trailX.Count - 1
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(trailcolour, planet.trailX(drawTrail), planet.trailY(drawTrail), 1, 1) 'Draw a pixel at the planet's current location
Next
```

And this is in a timer event which ticks 60 times a second:

```
trailDots += 1
ReDim Preserve planet.trailX(trailDots)
ReDim Preserve planet.trailY(trailDots)
planet.trailX(trailDots) = planet.displayX
planet.trailY(trailDots) = planet.displayY
```

I tried adding this code in the timer tick:

```
If trailDots > 1000 Then
    trailDots -= 1
    ReDim Preserve planet.trailX(trailDots - 1)
    ReDim Preserve planet.trailY(trailDots - 1)
End If
```

But once the trail got to 1000 dots the simulation crashes with the message "IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled" on the line "planet.trailX(trailDots) = planet.displayX"

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you would be better off implementing a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). It would eliminate the need to keep redimming arrays.

Comment: Instead of using arrays, You might be better using a list. That way, you can add items to the end and when you get to 1000 dots, remove item 0. Intstead of using a separate variable to track the number of dots, you can use the .count property of the lists. And for displaying the dots, just use a For Each loop iterating through the lists. Easy :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you are removing the newest element and not the oldest.

Anyway, the reason it crashes is because you first decrease trailDots by one and then redim it to trailDots - 1, effectively shrinking it by 2 elements. You can make the following changes to fix that.

```
If trailDots > 1000 Then
    trailDots -= 1
    ReDim Preserve planet.trailX(trailDots)
    ReDim Preserve planet.trailY(trailDots)
End If
```

I would also recommend to initialize trailDots to 0 and make the following changes.

```
planet.trailX(trailDots - 1) = planet.displayX
planet.trailY(trailDots - 1) = planet.displayY
```

But as Andew said, you should rather use circular buffer for this problem.